# Autogenerating EJB3.0 Entity Beans

Tags: ejb-3.0

Is there any ant task based tool using which, we can generate annotation based entity bean code (EJB3.X).

IDE based tool is not prefreable

Thanks in advance
Vivek Shah

Comment: To be sure, do you mean JPA entities?  There are no EJB-based entity annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to [hibernate tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html), which are able to do **database reverse engineering** to create JPA entities (EJB) from the tables of the database:

> The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is a database reverse engineering tool that can generate domain model classes and Hibernate mapping files, annotated EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation or even an entire JBoss Seam application in seconds!